# Add a Column to a Table via Linq or Triggers in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, triggers

The issue is like , I got two tables X & Y. When records are added to table X , columns should be added to the table Y in parallel.

http://prntscr.com/3owqfe  <-- Provides a clear Idea.

I tried it with triggers , but seems like the triggers doesnt allow CREATE TABLE or ALTER  TABLE. Anyway as I'm using Linq , Im trying to achieve that via Linq. Any suggestions ?

Edited: For the record the below trigger worked , but with an exception.

```
create trigger AddItemToCommon ON [SEP].[dbo].[ItemMaster]
FOR INSERT 
AS BEGIN 

declare @PAYID varchar(max) 

select @PAYID = payCode from INSERTED 

ALTER TABLE [SEP].[dbo].[CommonPayrollItems] 
ADD sampleCol varchar(max)

END
```

Anyway it will only run once because , there cannot be more than 1 column of the same name. But if I can retrieve the row values grom ItemMaster table , it's still possible with triggers. Which I tried to replace sampleCol with @PAYID which results in Syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq does not have functionality to create or alter tables. You could however use the underlying connection of your Linq Datacontext to execute any SQL statement:

[DataContext.ExecuteCommand(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And use that to run your `alter table` statement. This will not update your Linq model of that table though.

If you plan to do this at runtime, you might want to reconsider your data model and create a third table (eg. `STable2Extended`) that contains a foreign key to both `STable` and `STable2` combined with the applicable value for that column.
You could then add the `STable2Extended` to the datamodel and query it easily when you need the extended properties on `STable2` without dynamically modifying tables.